# How to validate web hook signature in coinbase commerce

Tags: php, webhooks, coinbase-api

I wanted to create a webhook signature validator for coinbase commece webhook but I am always getting signature is invalid.

Here is my code when comparing

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // The request is using the POST method

    //getting request body
    $payload = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $transaction = json_decode($payload);

    if ($transaction->event->type) {
        $myHash = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, 'xx coinbase secret xx', true));

        if ($myHash === $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CC_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE']) {
            echo "The signature is valid";
        } else {
            echo "The signature is invalid";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'please there was an error';
    }
}
```

But I am getting invalid. I want to know if I am doing anything wrong so I can work on it

Comment: The docs say `The signature is included as a X-CC-Webhook-Signature header. This header contains the SHA256 HMAC signature of the raw request payload, computed using your webhook shared secret as the key.` but you're using `HTTP_X_CC_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE`. I don't know much about PHP but it looks like you're looking at the wrong header possibly? Apologies if that's how it translates to the php header.

Comment: hello @Travis well what i inputed there was actually what i was meant to insert.

its actually a convection for php

Answer (score -1):

There's a [Coinbase Commerce API PHP](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-commerce-php) library that you can use.

However, if you prefer to code it yourself, this is how you can:

```
<?php

$rawBody = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $rawBody, 'your shared seceret');
$webhookSignature = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CC_WEBHOOK_SIGNATURE'];

if (hash_equals($webhookSignature, $hash)) {
    print 'VALID';
}
```

We can wrap it in a function.

```
// returns boolean (true|false)
function verifySignature($signature, $rawBody, $sharedSecret)
{
    $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $rawBody, $sharedSecret);
    return hash_equals($signature, $hash);
}


// calling the function
verifySignature($webhookSignature, $rawBody, 'your shared seceret');
```